# Retry failing Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a few functional tests in Jasmine that will periodically fail due to something in the DOM not having finished composing.  I would like to be able to have these tests retry a couple of times rather than failing the test suite.

I'm looking for something similar to the way that Mocha behaves with https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests or, even better, the ability to specify a wait and then retry.

Comment: have you searched in Jasmine's website or GitHub issues page? I'm certain it was asked before.

Comment: Yeah; I ended up getting an answer on their GitHub issues that they do not support this as the developers believe it is a bad practice.  Wish I had known back when we were picking our testing framework; we would have gone with Mocha instead.

Comment: you should answer here you you have learnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Jasmine's owner:

> this is functionality we'd like to keep out of jasmine itself.

source: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/960

[protractor-flake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake) has been recommended to solve this, assuming you are using Protractor.